# Can I build Rstudio server from sources

Tags: r, build, rstudio-server

I work on a `centOS 6.6` distro and would like to use Rstudio. I would like to use an up to date version say `v>0.99` but from [the download page](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/) I can see that Rstudio desktop requires `RHEL7`.

Looking for [older versions of rstudio desktop](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206569407-Older-Versions-of-RStudio) I see that `RHEL6` can only get `v<=0.981103`, though [Rstudio server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/) seems fine, and I am OK if many can use a server version.

`rpm` is a no go for me so **is there a way to get the sources for the server version like they provide for the `desktop` version ?** I can't find it anywhere but it appears it is possible: [see this post](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200717183-RStudio-Server-Installation-Problems).

Of course if there is a trick to build Rstudio desktop on centOS 6.6 I am a buyer...

Comment: Try reading [this file in the corresponding source repo helpfully named INSTALL](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/INSTALL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to build RStudio Desktop for RHEL6 because of a glibc requirement induced by Qt 5.4. This is not easily evaded so if you have a platform requirement for RHEL6 you'll want to stick with the server version.

The desktop and server versions of RStudio are actually built from the same source code. You can get the source for any RStudio release here:

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/releases

The `make-package Server RPM` command in `rstudio/package/linux` will start the build once you've got all the dependencies installed. See here for details (or `INSTALL`): https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/wiki/Installing-RStudio-Dependencies